# Spring/JPA PostgreSQL - Spring Data Auditing INTEGER instead of bytea, Envers

Tags: spring, hibernate, postgresql, jpa, spring-data

In my Spring/JPA/Hibernate/Envers PostgreSQL application I'm trying to implement [Spring Data Auditing](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.5.0.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html)

I have a following entity:

```
@Audited
@AuditTable("levels_history")
@Entity
@Table(name = "levels")
public class Level extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 642499791438799548L;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "levels_id_seq", sequenceName = "levels_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "levels_id_seq")
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @NotAudited
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "level")
    private List<Card> card = new ArrayList<Card>();

    @CreatedBy
    @Column(name = "created_by_user_id")
    private User createdByUser;

    @LastModifiedBy
    @Column(name = "last_modified_by_user_id")
    private User lastModifiedByUser;
```

where I have added:

```
    @CreatedBy
    @Column(name = "created_by_user_id")
    private User createdByUser;

    @LastModifiedBy
    @Column(name = "last_modified_by_user_id")
    private User lastModifiedByUser;
```

at the database level I want to write `INTEGER` ID for `created_by_user_id` and `last_modified_by_user_id` but during execution my application throws an error that `created_by_user_id` should be `bytea` type.

What am I doing wrong and how to configure Spring Data Auditing to use `INTEGER` for this purpose ?

Comment: If you're trying reference a User table by User_Id you should specify with a @ManyToOne mapping.  I don't use spring so I'm not sure if there's something different going on here.

Comment: Thanks! you are right